# Does Password Expiry\ password reset invalidates MSTeams OAuth 2.0 Refresh Token?

Tags: oauth-2.0, microsoft-teams, refresh-token, microsoft-graph-teams

We are using MSTeams Oauth2.0 for getting user token. For MSTeams the refresh_token has the validity of 90 days and once it expires it throws invalid_grant error.

If the User's password got expired or the User\Admin resets the password will within the 90 days will that also invalidated the access_token and refresh_token ?

Comment: Hi @Kumar Tech, yes, When ever your password gets expired and even admin resets the password, then also it will invalidate the access/refresh tokens.

Answer (score 0):

**Posting the Answer for better knowledge**

**Copying from comments**

yes, When ever your password gets expired and even admin resets the password, then also it will invalidate the access/refresh tokens.